# Why would a custom Node.js CLI work with npm link, but not when installed on Windows?

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface

I've created a Node.js command line tool on Mac. I've tested it using `npm link` and there don't seem to be any problems. Others have installed it on Mac, and it seems to work. When installed on Windows, the CLI will run up until it gets to the point where it needs to create files. At that point, the CLI exits with no errors. Using `npm link` on Windows does result in a working solution, however.

The CLI itself uses Node 4.x and has no external dependencies. All file operations are done using the `fs` module. If you would like to investigate further, the full source code is available here: https://github.com/aurelia/cli It's also published on npm under the name `aurelia-cli`.

Comment: It sounds like you need to see what is causing it to exit, probably an exception being thrown.  That would be your biggest clue.

Comment: have any output do give us ? You may also want to spin up windows via vagrant or testing purpose, i can give you example if you d like to. Try also npm i -g on your box instead of npm link.

Answer (score 0):

We finally figured it out. I'm still not sure why the exception was being swallowed but we were able to track it down by installing on windows, going to the install location and manually tracking progress with console logs and strategic try/catch blocks. Interestingly, it was caused by a require of a file which was missing. This caused execution to halt. We still haven't figured out why this only happened on windows, because the missing file was due to a gitignore, which seems like it should have affected all installs. However, we were able to easily solve the problem and publish the fix.